# Component ID has already been found in the view. Duplicate ui:repeat element after executing ajax functionality

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, uirepeat

I am using JSF Mojarra 2.2 and Primefaces 4.0.

On my page I use `<ui:repeat>` to render some dataTables. By clicking on the name column of a single row-element additional information for this row is loaded via ajax and displayed below the tables in a separate panel. The page renders normally and behaves as expected in the beginning. After some clicks and loading additional information via ajax I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID has already been found in the view.
```

**The detailed error message**

```
+id: dcvForm
 type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm@19aa202
  +id: j_idt34
   type: org.primefaces.component.scrollpanel.ScrollPanel@1025e3c
    +id: j_idt35
     type: org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanel@78eb00
      +id: j_idt40  <===============
       type: com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat@194a115
        +id: j_idt41
         type: org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable@db8d63
          +id: j_idt42
           type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1f6f6f
          +id: j_idt43
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@1ccf811
            +id: j_idt44
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1b22d38
            +id: j_idt45
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@b6cbe4
          +id: j_idt46
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@103f78a
            +id: j_idt47
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1708cb9
            +id: j_idt48
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@26ed67
          +id: j_idt49
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@1ac1194
            +id: j_idt50
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1b61dd7
            +id: j_idt51
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1614aa1
          +id: j_idt52
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@6a93d0
            +id: j_idt53
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@10e3ef3
            +id: j_idt54
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@46fd81
          +id: j_idt55
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@ad5082
            +id: j_idt56
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@808a3a
            +id: j_idt57
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@f31547
      +id: j_idt40  <===============
       type: com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat@fa2760
        +id: j_idt41
         type: org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable@12f4785
          +id: j_idt42
           type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1007ab4
          +id: j_idt43
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@77deb5
            +id: j_idt44
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1be73ae
            +id: j_idt45
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@9cd7aa
          +id: j_idt46
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@113119b
            +id: j_idt47
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@e8ee3b
            +id: j_idt48
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@7083c1
          +id: j_idt49
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@da0bb8
            +id: j_idt50
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1378ca7
            +id: j_idt51
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1f360fc
          +id: j_idt52
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@16454e1
            +id: j_idt53
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@aea7
            +id: j_idt54
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@ca6240
          +id: j_idt55
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@f8833d
            +id: j_idt56
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@17033ef
            +id: j_idt57
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@161bdc8
      +id: j_idt36
       type: org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable@8c5a93
        +id: j_idt37
         type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@8ea6b9
        +id: j_idt38
         type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@163dfdf
          +id: j_idt39
           type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1fec9fc
          +id: ElementName
           type: org.primefaces.component.commandlink.CommandLink@7edb15
          +id: ceIndex
           type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputHidden@617652
      +id: j_idt40
       type: com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat@9f1948
        +id: j_idt41
         type: org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable@134c649
          +id: j_idt42
           type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1c60a38
          +id: j_idt43
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@c9054a
            +id: j_idt44
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@17a7e4d
            +id: j_idt45
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@fa11ca
          +id: j_idt46
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@1a5e64c
            +id: j_idt47
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@b2c0d7
            +id: j_idt48
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1929f1c
          +id: j_idt49
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@10be919
            +id: j_idt50
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@f47006
            +id: j_idt51
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1e6c683
          +id: j_idt52
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@1f2e85c
            +id: j_idt53
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@7517ff
            +id: j_idt54
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@17a69a8
          +id: j_idt55
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@1aececc
            +id: j_idt56
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@18ac146
            +id: j_idt57
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@9714e6
  +id: j_idt58
   type: 
        <p/>

  +id: filterInfoPanel
   type: org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanel@dd2f52
    +id: j_idt59
     type: com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat@14ddafe
      +id: j_idt60
       type: org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanel@64760f
        +id: j_idt61
         type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputLabel@183001f
        +id: j_idt62
         type: 
                    <p/>

        +id: j_idt63
         type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputLabel@17d098a
    +id: ajaxStatusPanel
     type: org.primefaces.component.ajaxstatus.AjaxStatus@1fd5640
      +id: j_idt64
       type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlGraphicImage@1299e6a
      +id: j_idt65
       type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlGraphicImage@15f6084
+id: j_idt66
 type:          
    </div>
```

**My xhtml page**

```html
<ui:define name="content">
                    <h:form id="dcvForm">
                        <p:scrollPanel mode="native">
                            <p:outputPanel style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                <p:dataTable var="rowElement" binding="#{nameTable}"
                                    value="#{domainComparisonBean.firstDomainElements}"
                                    style="display:inline-block;">
                            [...]   
                                        <p:commandLink id="ElementName" value="#{rowElement.name}"
                                            actionListener="#{domainComparisonBean.mouseOver}"
                                            update=":dcvForm:filterInfoPanel" ajax="true" >
                                        </p:commandLink>
                            [...]
                                </p:dataTable>

                                <ui:repeat var="domain" value="#{domainComparisonBean.domainData}"
                                    varStatus="status">
                                    <p:dataTable var="rowElement" value="#{domain.rowData}"
                                        style="display:inline-block;" selectionMode="single"
                                        selection="#{domainComparisonBean.selectedRow}">

                            [...]

                                    </p:dataTable>
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </p:scrollPanel>
                        <p />
                        <p:outputPanel id="filterInfoPanel"
                            style="border:none; margin-left:10px;">
                            <ui:repeat var="filter"
                                value="#{domainComparisonBean.currentFilters}" varStatus="status">
                            [...]               
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </h:form>
                </ui:define>
```

It seems that by mistake the `<ui:repeat>` is inserted multiple times with the same id into the document tree.

The problem only occurs in combination with ajax functionality. If I set `ajax="false"` in my `<p:commandLink>` I do not get any errors.

Please help me understand why this happens and how to avoid it!

Comment: Which Mojarra version exactly? 2.2.0? Tried the latest? In any way, try giving the affecting component a fixed ID. More than often this fixes that kind of complex state saving trouble. Alternatively, replace `<ui:repeat>` by `<p:dataList type="none">`. On contrary to Mojarra's `UIRepeat`, the `UIData` based components have a much more robust state saving implementation.

Comment: I have updated to Mojarra 2.2.5 but the error still remains. Giving the affected `<ui:repeat id="tableRepeat">` just leads to `+id: tableRepeat  <===============
           type: com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat@148bce2` in the error message

Comment: OK, well, try another repeater component. Mojarra's `UIRepeat` has previously been soo full of state saving bugs. A lot has been fixed, but this is apparently another oversight.

Comment: I tried `<p:dataList>` and I do not get the error now any more. Thank you! However, my content was shown next to each other before (vertically) and is now shown under each other (horizontally). Do you have a tip how I could achieve the vertical positioning with the `<p:dataList>`?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot `type="none"`?

Comment: No, the problem is not inside the `<p:dataList>` but the element itself. I try to make it float by setting `style="display:inline-block;"` but it still breaks.

Comment: Well, press "Ask Question" button on the top right and post an SSCCE. Current question is technically already answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by BalusC in the comments, I used `<p:dataList type="none">` to replace `<ui:repeat>` which solves the error.